# Как создать метод используя JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Привет. Пытаюсь написать метод updateUser с помощью которого можно менять все данные в таблице **SQL**. Мой Query выглядит так

```
String updateValue = "update users_Alana set name = :name, gender = :gender, age = :age where id = :id";
```

Метод так

```
public static User updateUser(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, int id){
        User user = new User();

        SqlParameterSource p2 = new MapSqlParameterSource("id", Integer.valueOf(id));
        user.setAge(5);
        user.setGender("m");
        user.setName("Bartek");
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(updateValue, p2,new UserMapper());
    }
```

И еще мой userMapper выглядит так private static class UserMapper implements

```
RowMapper<User> {
        @Nullable
        public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            user.setGender(resultSet.getString("gender"));
            user.setAge(resultSet.getInt("age"));
            return user;
        }
    }
```

Метод должен выводить измененную линию.
Когда пытаюсь скомпилировать то выдает кучу ошибок.
Как исправить данный метод? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Надо положить все нужные для запроса поля объекта в `MapSqlParameterSource`.

Либо используйте `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource`

---

В Вашем случае

```
MapSqlParameterSource p2 = new MapSqlParameterSource();
```

а дальше добавлять параметры запроса через `p2.addValue`

Comment: можно узнать как это сделать в моем случае? Как то так ?SqlParameterSource p2 = new MapSqlParameterSource("id",3);     SqlParameterSource p3 = new MapSqlParameterSource("name","Dawid");   и т.д.